# How to allow only users associated with certain permissions to access certain urls in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to figure out how to allow certain users who have a value: ifAdmin=True the ability to edit a project page. That being said, I have a model called uProjects that associates a user and a project with a uProjects, and I am currently trying to use the @wraps function, but would welcome a different approach, or a correction on my code because I am returned the HttpResponseRedirect when I am logged in with a user who has ifAdmin=True and I try to edit a project associated with the uProjects for that user. Here is my code:

model:

```
class uProjects(models.Model):
   
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ifAccepted = models.BooleanField(null = True, blank=False, default=False)
    #ifLeader = models.BooleanField(null = False, blank=False)
    ifAdmin = models.BooleanField(null = True, blank=False, default=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + ',' + self.project.name
```

views.py

```
def admin_check(function):
  @wraps(function)
  def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        name = kwargs.get('name')  
        if uProjects.objects.filter(title=name, user=user, ifAdmin=True).exists():
             return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

  return wrap

@admin_check
def update(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        pr_form = ProjectUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                    request.FILES,
                                    instance=request.project.name)
   
        if pr_form.is_valid():
            pr_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'This project has been updated.')
            return redirect('project')
        
    else:
        pr_form = ProjectUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {
        'pr_form': pr_form
    }
    return render(request, 'projects/updateproject.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/',v.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/<int:id>/',v.profile, name='profile1'),
    path('profile/',v.profile1, name='profile'),
    path('home/',v.home, name='home'),
    path('noti/',n.Notifications, name='noti'),
    path('invite/',n.invite, name='invite'),
    path('accept/<str:name1>/<int:id>/', n.accept, name='accept'),
    path('project/<str:name>/request/<int:id>', n.request, name= 'request'),
    path('allow/<str:name1>/<int:id>/', n.allow, name = 'allow'),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path('', include('projects.urls')),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='registration/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    #url(r'^updateprofile', v.updateprofile),
    path('updateprofile/', v.updateprofile, name='updateprofile'),
    path('createproject/', p.createProject, name='createproject'),
    path('project/<str:name>/', p.project, name='project'),
    path('editproject/', p.update, name="editproject"),
    path('agree/', include('Notifications.urls')),
]
```

projects.models.py

````
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    #owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    bPic = models.ImageField(default='defaultproban.jpg', upload_to='project_banner')
    logo = models.ImageField(default='defaultlogo.jpg', upload_to='project_logo')
    dep_choice1 = (
        ('Behavioral Sciences and Leadership', ('Behavioral Sciences and Leadership')),
        ('Chemistry and Life Science', ('Chemistry and Life Science')),
        ('Civil and Mechanical Engineering', ('Civil and Mechanical Engineering')),
        ('Electrical Engineering and Comptuer Science', ('Electrical Engineering and Comptuer Science')),
        ('English and Philosophy', ('English and Philosophy')),
        ('Foreign Languages', ('Foreign Languages')),
        ('Geography and Environmental Engineering', ('Geography and Environmental Engineering')),
        ('History', ('History')),
        ('Law', ('Law')),
        ('Mathematical Sciences', ('Mathematical Sciences')),
        ('Physics and Nuclear Engineering', ('Physics and Nuclear Engineering')),
        ('Social Sciences', ('Social Sciences')),
        ('Systems Engineering', ('Systems Engineering')),
        ('Independent', ('Independent')),
    )
    department = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=dep_choice1,
        default='Independent',
    )
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, null = True)
    purpose=models.TextField()
    tag_choice = (
        ('Data Analysis' , ('Data Analysis')),
        ('3D Printing' , ('3D Printing')),
        ('Robotics' , ('Robotics')),
        ('Coding' , ('Coding')),
        ('Frauds' , ('Frauds, AKA Law majors')),
    )

    projectTag = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        choices=tag_choice,
        default='Frauds',
    )

    look = (
        ('motivated cadets with niche expertise.', ('Expert Cadets')),
        ('cadets who want to learn and help.', ('Any cadet who wants to help')),
        ('an engineering cadet.', ('Engineering Cadet')),
        ('a cadet with a scientific background.', ('Scientific background')),
        ('cadets with programming experience.', ('Coding Background')),
       
    )
    
    lookingFor = models.CharField(
        max_length=75,
        choices=look,
        default='an engineering cadet,',
    )

    recruit = (
        ('Yes', ('Yes')),
        ('No', ('No')),
    )

    recruiting = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=recruit,
        default='Yes',
    )
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural= "projects"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name```
Right now, this code doesn't work because when I am logged in with a user who has ifAdmin = True for a uProject, and I try to edit the project page associated with that uProject, I am returned the HttpResponseRedirect('/')
````

Comment: In your model, is the foreign key to `User` the builtin User class from Django's `auth` module? If you run this query in the console, does it return an existing record? Are you sure that `kwargs.get('name')` is returning what is expected?

Comment: @sytech Just tried to run it in the console and I got an error because name is not defined. How do I check if kwargs.get('name') returns what is expected?

Comment: You could add debug logging (or even simple print statements) for testing purposes. Also, as a side note: `update` does not accept keyword arguments, so, assuming there is a keyword argument `name`, then `function(request, *args, **kwargs)` would raise an error for an unexpected keyword argument, even if your condition catches correctly. Where are you expecting keyword from? Is it an argument from the URL path? If so, can you post your `urls.py`?

Comment: @sytech I am expecting the name from my url path and I have included the code with an edit in my post.

Comment: Does that update contain the `update` view? The only thing I see that might be it is `path('editproject/', p.update, name="editproject"),` but it doesn't look like this path accepts any arguments.

Comment: @syteceh the update view is already in the original post. There is a path ```path('project/<str:name>/', p.project, name='project')``` but when I try to add ```/<str:name>/'``` to the ```editproject``` path, when I go to access that page, I get an error of "Reverse for 'editproject' with no arguments not found.1 pattern(s) tried: ['editproject/(?P<name>[^/]+)/$'].

Comment: I don't see any code for a function named `project` though, just `update`.  You get the error because you need to go to `/editproject/something` or add an additional route without the argument to make it optional, if that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: Oh gotcha, sorry I just updated it. I don't really need to do that with editprojects, I just want to be able to have only certain users with ifAdmin be able to access that url.